# Алгоритм отправки сообщений

Tags: алгоритм, php, javascript

Друзья! Помогите придумать алгоритм для следующей задачи:

Нужно программно повторить поведение человека отправляющего сообщения, например в твиттер. Есть, скажем, 100 готовых сообщений. Во-время начала дня уходит одно сообщение, в обеденный час - 20 сообщений. От начала дня до обеда сообщения должна отправляться все чаще и чаще, а после обеда наоборот. Получаем вид как у нормального распределения.

Как решение этой задачи можно описать? Реализация не важна.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Сделайте выборку из `100` случайных величин от `0` до `1` с нормальным распределением, отсортируйте в возрастающем порядке и умножьте каждое число, скажем, на отрезок `[07:15, 23:30].`

> Если что, то умножение *числа* на *отрезок* - это не строгая математическая операция `:)`

- Вы получите последовательность вида `{07:18, 07:23, 07:43, ...}`, и именно в эти моменты времени нужно отправлять сообщения.

Comment: умножьте каждое число, скажем, на отрезок [07:15, 23:30]
Не совсем понял как умножить число на отрезок?

Comment: @psyho_Octopus `07:15 + (23:30 - 07:15) * t`

Comment: Только с таким решением не выполняется условие что сообщения к обеду будут отправляться чаще и чаще. Например:

8-00 9-00 9-30 10-00 10-20 10-40 11-00 11-10 11-20 11-30 ...

Comment: @psyho_Octopus Да? А почему вы полагаете, что это условие не выполняется?

Comment: Возможно я не понял как сделать выборку из 100 случайных величин от 0 до 1 с нормальным распределением. Не подскажете?